# Have a Promise wait for a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have a plugin I'm writing for a framework that uses Promises throughout.
The plugin is expected to return a Promise to process the event, and anything the plugin does during processing is chained before returning the next event.
I think...

Anyway - I am also using an older library that is completely callback based - and the callback doesn't follow the standard convention of having callback(err,resp) as the last parameter.

How do I turn this:

```
var call = libary.Api(_this.config.url, function(response){return new Promise() {Do my actions with the response..}}, _this.config.api_key);

return BbPromise.try(call).then(evt);
```

Into a Promise that depends on the callback being processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (new BbPromise(function(resolve) {
    libary.Api(_this.config.url, function(response) {
        resolve(response);
    }, _this.config.api_key);
})).then(evt);
```